# Sagemaker pipeline

Tags: pipeline, amazon-sagemaker

I defined new pipeline code from sagemaker abalone pipeline but I ended up using same pipeline as abalone pipeline [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZZYh.png)

What should I do? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that the JSON definition of the new pipeline is different to the original abalone pipeline.

When using the Python SDK, you can create the Pipeline and it has a function `.definition()` that you can use to check the Pipeline before you run `pipeline.upsert()` to create/update the Pipeline. If you've changed the code and updated the pipeline through `upsert()`, you should see the new Pipeline.

I work at AWS and my opinions are my own.